# Generator of the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ for $a>0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Let $a$ be an integer $>0$. The additive group $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group. I would like to show that
>   $$\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}=\{X\ |\ (\exists n)(n\in\mathbb{Z}\ \land X=n\cdot(a\mathbb{Z}+1))\}.$$

**Attempt:**

Let $X\in\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$: there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $X=a\mathbb{Z}+m$. I read somewhere that
$$m(a\mathbb{Z}+1)=m(a\mathbb{Z})+m=a\mathbb{Z}+m.$$
But is this true? For example, let $m=0$: then this would imply that 
$$0(a\mathbb{Z}+1)=0(a\mathbb{Z})+0\cdot1=0\ne a\mathbb{Z}.$$

What am I doing wrong? I would like to show that $a\mathbb{Z}+1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Suppose $a=\frac{1}{2}$. What should be $\mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I  guess you implicitly suppose  $a$ is a positive *integer*.

What you misunderstood is how $\;m\cdot(1+a\mathbf Z)\;$ is defined:

Suppose first $m=2$: by definition
$$2(1+a\mathbf Z)=(1+a\mathbf Z)+(1+a\mathbf Z)=(1+1)+a\mathbf Z=2+a\mathbf Z,$$
and more generally:
$$m(1+a\mathbf Z)=m\cdot 1+a\mathbf Z=m+a\mathbf Z,$$
not $\;m+ma\mathbf Z$.